# Global queue accessible from bottle API in python

Tags: python, multithreading, rest, global-variables, bottle

So basically I have two threads, one is running the bottle api, which has a post call. I want to be able to post to this api, and then the api will push some data from the post to the global queue, and the other thread catches this and does something with it. How do I make this queue object accessible from the post call?

```
def publisher(q):
    while 1:
       q.get()
       #do stuff

def main():
    q = Queue(maxsize=0)
    b = Process(target=run, kwargs=dict(host='localhost', port=1313, debug=True))
    s = Process(target=publisher, args=(q,)
    b.start()
    s.start()

@post('/process')
def my_process():
  req_obj = json.loads(request.body.read())
  q.put(req_obj)
```

Comment: Don't. Use a proper separate task queue like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: My "short" solution won't work as-is because of the multiple processes attempting to share the queue object. See comments for more info.

Short answer: Move `q` to global scope. (No other changes required.)

```
q = Queue(maxsize=0)

def publisher(q):
    while 1:
       q.get()
       #do stuff

def main():
    b = Process(target=run, kwargs=dict(host='localhost', port=1313, debug=True))
    s = Process(target=publisher, args=(q,)
    b.start()
    s.start()

@post('/process')
def my_process():
  req_obj = json.loads(request.body.read())
  q.put(req_obj)
```

Long answer: Use a separate task queue as @DanielRoseman suggests.

Comment: this actually doesn't work, the two threads are using different queues or something

Comment: Ah, I missed that. You might be able to get it working with a Manager (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) but I'd suggest using a proper cross-process queue instead.